# Xfce4 Alt F2 - xfrun4 command impotent in 14.04 Trusty

Tags: 14.04, xfce

I get used to run simple commands using Alt+F2 shortcut in 12.04 LTS Precise.
Most of them needed sudo, others dont but mostly those are simply terminal commands.
So there must be checked "Run in terminal", and if started by sudo, password was asked. But even xnc4viewer,asked for password.. in terminal.

Now there is no checkbox to "Run in terminal". So, I can run almost nothing now, after upgrade in Trusty 14.04 LTS. Each time have to start xterm, and command history is very different too..
Only GUI applications.. terminal commands dont run, or they stay hidden somewhere in invisible space? Seems to me, it is replacement to void value app, instead of very usefull one.

Probably, I just do not know howto use it. But Google did not help me this time.
I do not know how to configure something like xfrun4,  or how to downgrade whole xfce4 (yes I would be happy), or whatever app can be used instead, or what else I could do to return xfce4 to state how it was in 12.04 LTS Precise. 
I think I must use Trusty, because of new hardware (some Intel Haswell and Baytrail boards).

Comment: Rather then downgrading xfce (or other drastic mesures), just use 12.04 with [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) from 14.04. Packages are already in the repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

1. Press Alt+F2 then press the green arrow (Toggle view mode)
2. Open the Preferences and add a new pattern, the command should be:

   > xfce4-terminal -x bash -ic "%s ; bash"

   (-ic to run interactive shell, what will you allow to use the aliases from .bashrc)
3. Try a command like the example shows

If you want that the Terminal close immediately after running the command you can just use the standard pattern "!".

Comment: YES sir, thank You very much. I must save this "howto" in some gold book of what I must do after each installation.