# Run command don't run command line programs

Tags: unity, command-line

In Unity there is some menu called "Execute a command", which could be run by shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. It is working fine only when I try to use it to run GUI programs like e.g. `gedit`.

It is completely not working when I put command which try run command line program like: `vim test.txt`After that there is no error message simply nothing happen. It is some bug or some "feature"?

How could I run command line programs inside Ubuntu/Unity without running "Terminal"?

Comment: In Xubuntu this is no problem (with a pattern) http://askubuntu.com/questions/492876/xfce4-alt-f2-xfrun4-command-impotent-in-14-04-trusty/492886 , perhaps there is something similar in Unity, don't know.... The program is called `xfrun4`.

Comment: @Tuknux indeed in the example, A terminal is defined in the preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line applications will use *a* terminal anyhow. If you want to edit `test.txt` with vim, you still need to say which terminal you want to use. The full command you have to enter, assuming you run vim in gnome-terminal (using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) is:

```
gnome-terminal -x vim test.txt
```

Than it works.

Comment: Thanks. It is working, but it is much to complicated to be usable. I'm really searching for some command runner, which has auto completion, build in history of last executed commands, and allow  to run UI and command line programs without adding that prefix. Simple “vim test.txt” or “gedit test.txt” should be enough.

Comment: @Kendzi You are making a thinking error, vim and other command line applications only work through a terminal application (there are several). They do not bring a terminal window of their own. The consequence is that you have to say which terminal vim should run in. There is no other option. Gedit, as you mentioned, brings a window of its own.

Comment: You are not right. I just test "gmrun" and it manage to open both UI and command line programs without say which terminal vim should run in. Unfortunately "gmrun" don't have auto completion and history.

Comment: @Kendzi I don't know the gmrun command (it does nothing here), but anyway or anywhere, a terminal is defined

Comment: it seems i have ask wrong question. It should be more on finding replacement for default command runner. Maybe that runner already exist and there is no need to write it. I ask new question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/502261/unity-command-runner

Comment: @Kendzi hey! I also needed a possibility to run an arbitrary command via dash and ended up just with a custom .sh-script that I call from dash. The content of the script is `gnome-terminal -x mycommand` and the script is also in $PATH.