# Can Alt+F2(running command prompt shortcut) shortcut run commands with root permission?

Tags: command-line, permissions, 20.04, shortcut-keys

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and I tried something on run console. I typed `sudo -i` and nothing happened when I pressed enter button. I assumed that I became superuser on GUI first.
I tried to check it by using terminal with `whoami` command and it said my default username.Then,I used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut again and I tried typing a command that needs root permission to be run like `sudo cat /etc/shadow` and nothing happened again.
Moreover,I typed something meaningless and it said `Command not found`.
I mean it runs valid commands normally but I couldn't understand what happened after I typed `sudo -i` by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut.

Here is the screenshot to make it clear

[image]

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  (also clues as to using server, desktop & what desktop, as Alt+F2 does nothing on my system running a GUI; it's trapped & processed by whatever program I have active at the time)

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I wouldn't expect `sudo cat ...` to work for the same reasons I wouldn't expect `cat ...` to work i.e. there's no terminal for it to run *in*. See for example [Run command don't run command line programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502225/run-command-dont-run-command-line-programs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you typed `sudo -i` (or `sudo cat /etc/shadow`) the `sudo` command tried to read your password from the terminal. However, if you run the command that way, there is **no** terminal from which `sudo` could read the password; so it just aborted.

As @steeldriver noticed above, you need a terminal to run most command line tools (and `sudo` is one of them). Open a terminal first, and then type `sudo -i` in the terminal window.

If you want to run GUI (not command line) programs with root permission, the GUI alternative to `sudo` is `pkexec`; however it's usage is a bit more complicated than `sudo`. For example, that's how I run GNOME terminal window with root permissions:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gnome-terminal
```