# Unity command runner

Tags: unity

I'm searching for command runner for Unity. I known that there is default runner under shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. But as it was explained in that question [Run command don't run command line programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502225/run-command-dont-run-command-line-programs) it don't allow to run command lines programs without adding some prefixes to command.

In short I'm searching for command runner which:

- has auto completion
- has history of last used commands
- allow to run both commands `vim test.txt` or `gedit test.txt` without any prefixes, suffixes etc.
- if command line program was run, terminal window should be closed after exiting program

From different command runners I check `gmrun`, but it don't have auto completion or history. In other hand `xfrun4` as it is described in [Xfce4 Alt F2 - xfrun4 command impotent in 14.04 Trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492876/xfce4-alt-f2-xfrun4-command-impotent-in-14-04-trusty/492886) require some “!” prefix to work.

Do you known some command runner which could be integrated with Unity and meet that requirements?

Comment: my recommendation is just have a small popup terminal run at startup, I have one on my kde desktop and it works great

Comment: @sbergeron Yes I currently do it in the same way, but I don't want to have open terminal. I would like to simply run some command.

Comment: I think there are some for kde I just usually have an open terminal at all times with a new tab

Comment: Maybe a bit outdated, but you could look at the options here: http://lifehacker.com/5873738/the-best-application-launcher-for-linux

Comment: Gmrun has auto completion, history and can run `vi test.txt` with Ctrl+Enter http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gmrun-substitute-for-gnome-run-dialog-in-ubuntu.html. If you want more you have to use the terminal itself...

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Command Runner with the gnome-terminal:

First create a file `$HOME/.cmdrunrc`

The content should be:

```bash
# include .bashrc to load aliases from the .bashrc in the command runner
source .bashrc

# create a separated history file for the command runner
HISTFILE=~/.cmdrun_history

# shorten the command prompt
PS1='\w\$ '

# function to check an array if it contains an element
containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

# your guis which will not open a additional terminal window on execution 
guis=(firefox mousepad gedit geany leafpad nautilus thunar pcmanfm xterm) 

# after this commands finished the terminal will be closed automatically  
close_after=(vi nano top)

# the function that will be executed with every command
custom_run() { 
    if [ -n "$*" ]; then   
        # write the real command to the history without "custom_run" 
        history -s "$*"
        history -a

        # check if the command is an alias
        pure_cmd=$(echo "$*" | xargs | cut -d' ' -f1)
        if [ $(type -t "$pure_cmd") == "alias" ]; then
            # get the real command from the alias
            pure_cmd=$(type "$pure_cmd" | grep -oP "(?<=»)[^']+(?=«)")
            pure_cmd=$(echo "$pure_cmd" | cut -d' ' -f1)
        fi

        # check if command opens a gui or should be closed after it finished
        if containsElement "$pure_cmd" "${guis[@]}"; then
            bash -ic "($* &) &>/dev/null"
        elif containsElement "$pure_cmd" "${close_after[@]}"; then
            gnome-terminal -x bash -ic "$*"
        else
            gnome-terminal -x bash -ic "$*; bash"
        fi
    else
        # remove last command ("custom run") from history, if nothing is entered
        history -d $((HISTCMD-1))
    fi
    exit 0
}

# write the function "custom_run" before every command if the user presses return
bind 'RETURN: "\e[1~ custom_run "\e[4~"\n"'
```

Then create a .desktop file or a shell script with this command:

```
gnome-terminal --title="Command Runner" --hide-menubar --geometry="50x1" -x bash -ic "cd ~; bash --rcfile .cmdrunrc"
```